# Python with turtle: Turtle returning to 0,0 for no apparent reason

Tags: python-turtle

I am using repl.it to make a python with turtle program. I wanted to challenge myself to make whatever random name it generates (because it gives you a random name if none specified). I got FantasticEnchanting

so my idea was a package that had sparkles on it.

here comes the problem... for some reason the turtles responsible for making the sparkles are returning to (0,0)! I have never told them to do this!
now my code looks inefficient because it redefines turtle for every function but that's just because I had the same problem but with a different point! so I made them all turtles local to the function by defining them in the function! but instead of returning to the origin of the last square, they go to 0,0! I never told them to do either!

help would be amazing! have a nice day regardless!

you can find the project/code [here](https://repl.it/@SeamusDonahue/FantasticEnchantingPackage#main.py)

ps: the problem doesn't seem to be that the turtle starts at 0,0 it just goes back to 0,0 after the last circle function and before the up function even though I haven't told it to

Answer (score 0):

The turtle module is class based and each new instance starts at (0,0). You create a new instance every time you call the function:

```py
def sparkle(x, y, color="#55f", fill=True, size=None):
    t = turtle.Turtle();
    …
```

You should create a single instance and pass that single instance to the function every time the function is called.

```py
def sparkle(turtle, x, y, color="#55f", fill=True, size=None):
    …

t = turtle.Turtle();
spark(t, random.randint(-150, 150), random.randint(-150, 150))
spark(t, random.randint(-150, 150), random.randint(-150, 150))
```

Comment: I either don't understand what you mean or it doesn't fix the problem: I made one universal turtle: it made it worse... okay so one universal turtle and then a new one when making sparkles... didn't change anything. I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be doing

Comment: as for your edit, I am now making a new turtle every iteration of the for loop. that has not affected the program what so ever